# Facebook Open Graph Story Determiner not working

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am trying to use 'the' as the article for my object, but FB is simply ignoring it and is using 'a' instead.

When I run the object's url in FB's debugger I see all the info that's necessary.  All the other properties are being used just fine.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object types cannot use "the", only "a/an". So if your determiner isn't showing when not using the object's title, that's why.